# Encryption in peer to peer chat

Tags: encryption, rsa, protocols, key-exchange

For a homework assignment I'm developing a chat service that will be able to communicate within a single network. The communication channel should be encrypted with RSA.

Should I generate keypairs on every client and, when a client tries to communicate, ask for public key? Is this safe?

It is not a duplicate. I want to know what happen if somebody can't change packets over the network, and also offer authentication.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't we roll our own?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own)

Comment: I disagree with the duplicate suggestion.  While that link provides good information as to why production level shouldn't write their own protocols, for learning it is acceptable.

Comment: Why don't you just use [OTR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-the-Record_Messaging)?

Comment: OTR sound promising. i will study and then i will tell you if is it good.

Comment: @Volker Throw that in an Answer so we can upvote you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will answer your question in two parts:

> The communication channel should be encrypted with RSA. How can I do that?

RSA is really slow to encrypt whole messages. The usual way this is done is to encrypt the message with a symmetric cipher like AES, then encrypt the symmetric key using the recipient's RSA public key.

Having said that, there are *a lot* of small details to get right, so I would advise you to use a pre-built implementation. In fact, just use SSL/TLS, use-cases like yours are exactly what it's made for. `OpenSSL` in the most common TLS implementation, it's easy to use and will take care of all the crypto for you. Googling something like "introduction to openssl programming" should get you started.

EDIT: As @Volker pointed out in comments, many common instant messenger clients like Pidgin and Kopete use the library [Off-the-Record Messaging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-the-Record_Messaging) which is an encryption protocol specifically designed for instant messengers. OTR uses PGP as the underlying encryption system. There is an [OTR library for C available here](https://otr.cypherpunks.ca/index.php#downloads), and a [Java library here](https://code.google.com/p/otr4j/).

---

Now for the second part of your question:

> Generate keypairs on every client and when a client tries to communicate, ask for public key? It is this safe?

Let the SSL/TLS handshake take care of all this. It uses a key-exchange protocol called [Diffie-Hellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) which solves the key-exchange problem quite nicely.

One thing you will want to think about is whether you need strong authentication, ie whether or not you're worried about people impersonating other users. If so, you'll need to get everybody's public keys made into *certificates* that ties each public key to a specific person. This is a much more complicated setup that will require some sort of [Public Key Infrastructure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure) - either you'll have to setup a [Certificate Authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority) server (you can do it with `OpenSSL`), or have a web-of-trust system like PGP does. If you do decide to go this route, you can find info on Google, on this exchange, or you can post new question(s) about setting up a PKI for your chat network.

Answer (score 1):

I've written this type of chat service before.  When a user joins the server the public key for the client should be sent.  Then whenever a private message is started the server can distribute the public keys to the respective clients who are communicating.

You have to remember that using RSA to encrypt entire chat messages will be slow.  Which is why generally RSA is used in a key exchange to establish a long-term symmetric encryption key.  The key exchange establishes algorithms and security parameter too.  This allows for secure communication to be established for faster encryption methods without compromising security.

Checkout [How SSL/TLS Works](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work) for an in-depth look at how a secure protocol functions.  Keep in mind that writing your own secure protocols opens yourself up vulnerabilities.  ["Why shouldn't we roll or own?"](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own) addresses these concerns.